# How to avoid android signature problem when developing from two workspaces

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an app from two different workspace on two different PCs.
Code is shared with git.

Problem is - when I build an install the apk on my mobile (htc one m8) PC 1 and then continue on PC 2, deploy the apk, I cannot install it on this same mobile. I get an error that says that an app in with the same package alreasdy is installed, but the signatures do not match. 
I could certainly uninstall the app, then reinstall - but since I use databases, the uninstall would erase that data.

Is there a way to use the same signature on both PCs?

I use Eclipse with ADT and GenyMotion.

Comment: copy android debug key ... it should be in `USERHOME\.android\debug.keystore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same signature on multiple computers by copying the debug signing key between the computers (or including it in source control).

You can then set Eclipse to use that keystore for debug builds by opening the  Preferences > Android > Build menu.